# React reveal is installed properly but it is giving me error saying 'Module Not Found'

Tags: reactjs, module

I installed React Reveal using the command:
npm install react-reveal --save
I imported it on my react component by:
import Fade from 'react-reveal/Fade';
But it keeps giving me this error as shown in the screenshot[image: Compilation error]

I warped it on some of the divs to give them the effect but it don't seem to work :(
The code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Fade from 'react-reveal/Fade';

function Section({ title, description, backgroundImg, leftBtnText, rightBtnText }) {
    return (
        <Wrap
            style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/${backgroundImg})`,
            }}
        >
            <Fade bottom>
                <ItemText>
                    <h1>  {title} </h1>
                    <p>{description}</p>
                </ItemText>
            </Fade>
            <Buttons>
                <ButtonGroup>
                    <LeftButton>{leftBtnText}</LeftButton>
                    <RightButton>{rightBtnText}</RightButton>
                </ButtonGroup>

                <DownArrow src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/down-arrow.svg'} />

            </Buttons>

        </Wrap>
    );
}

export default Section;

const Wrap = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
`;

const ItemText = styled.div`
  padding-top: 15vh;
  text-align: center;
`;

const ButtonGroup = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-buttom: 30px;
  @media (max-width :768px) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
`;

const LeftButton = styled.button`
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 40px;
  width: 256px;
  color: #111111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  opacity: 0.85;
  margin: 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 8px;   
`;

const RightButton = styled.button`
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  height: 40px;
  width: 256px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  opacity: 0.85;
  margin: 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
`;
const DownArrow = styled.img`
    height: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    animation: animateDown infinite 1.5s;

`



const Buttons = styled.div``
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I add the --force command:

```
npm install react-reveal --save --force
```